# Why 360 video not working in Aframe.js in ASP.net core?

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

So, Its been more than two days. I have tried to follow every tutorial to upload the 360 video in my ASP.NET core. Earlier I was trying to mimic the website which I have mentioned in my previous question. Which is not working,  so I thought just to download the video from there and try to add it by using simple code:

```
html>
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-assets timeout="30000">
            <video id="urbanCity" src="~/video/progressive.mp4" autoplay></video>
        </a-assets>
        <a-camera>
            <a-cursor></a-cursor>
        </a-camera>

        <a-videosphere src="#urbanCity"></a-videosphere>
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the screenshot of my console:
[image: Console]

On my previous question someone relied that the timeout warning-->`core:a-assets:warn Asset loading timed out in   30000 ms` but in order to fix it I already added the aframe.js reference in head but no change can be observed.

This is the output of my screen. Its completely blank.
[image]

Comment: Is it black on mobile, PC, or both?

Comment: PC it is, I haven't checked it on mobile yet.

Comment: sorry for the long reply, did you manage to make it work, or You need help?